# How do I evaluate true or false for multiple conditions in a list

Tags: excel

I feel like this should be easy, but I'm at a loss. I'll do my best to describe example tables to suit my issue.

Table 1: -Cell A1 is labeled color with cells containing either "red", "blue" or "green" -Cell B1 is labled size with sizes ranging from 1 - 10. -Cell C3 is labled "candidate?" These cells will be either 1 or 0 depending on whether or not columns a and b match conditionals from table 2.

Table 2: -Cell E1 is labeled color and cell D1 is labeled size. -Cell E2 is blue, cell D2 is 5 -Cell E3 is red, cell D3 is 2

Basically I need a formula for cells in column C that will tell me if the values in column A match the value in column E and if the value in column B is greater than or equal to the corresponding value in column D.

Thanks for your help!

edit: apologies, I'm using the latest version of excel on a PC.

Comment: A picture would be worth 1000 words.  And an example of what you have tried, and where you are running into a problem would be worth more.  Suggest you edit your question after reading the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My apologies I should be saying column F instead of column D

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out it was

=IFERROR((INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(A2,$D:$D,0))<=B2)*1,0)